# djangorestframework does not reflect changes of resources

Tags: django-rest-framework

When I do some post/patch requests to django-rest-framework based web-service with curl in json format, I can see changes on admin page as well as in a database,but take some time for that figure to be reflected in the API (GET request)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not enough information here: what DBMS are you using? Which OS? Are you running the django development web server? Production web server? Which one? What's in your middleware configuration?

Comment: Thanks Jeff for his tip. The issue had to do with the 'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',

Comment: cool Im glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your middleware is the last thing in the **MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES**. 
As per docs from the django source-code:

**django.middleware.cache.py** ( django version 1.5 )

```
class UpdateCacheMiddleware(object):
    """
    Response-phase cache middleware that updates the cache if the response is
    cacheable.

    Must be used as part of the two-part update/fetch cache middleware.
    UpdateCacheMiddleware must be the first piece of middleware in
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES so that it'll get called last during the response phase.
    """
    # -- snip --

class FetchFromCacheMiddleware(object):
    """
    Request-phase cache middleware that fetches a page from the cache.

    Must be used as part of the two-part update/fetch cache middleware.
    FetchFromCacheMiddleware must be the last piece of middleware in
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES so that it'll get called last during the request phase.
    """
    # -- snip --

class CacheMiddleware(UpdateCacheMiddleware, FetchFromCacheMiddleware):
    """
    Cache middleware that provides basic behavior for many simple sites.

    Also used as the hook point for the cache decorator, which is generated
    using the decorator-from-middleware utility.
    """
    # -- snip --
```

Hope that helps